# Help with For Loop. Values repeating

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

```
$teams = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$game1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
$game2 = array();
```

if `teams[x]` is not in `game1` then insert into `game2`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($teams); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < count($game1); $j++){
        if($teams[$i] == $game1[$j]){
            break;
        } else {
            array_push($game2, $teams[$i]);
        }
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($game2); $i++) {
    echo $game2[$i];
    echo ", ";
}
```

Im expecting the result to be:

```
1, 3, 5, 7,
```

However, im getting:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8,
```

How can i improve this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already answered on how to use `array_diff`.

Reason why your existing loop does not work:

```
    if($teams[$i] == $game1[$j]){
        // this is correct, if item is found..you don't add.
        break; 
    } else {
        // this is incorrect!! we cannot say at this point that its not present.
        // even if it's not present you need to add it just once. But now you are
        // adding once for every test.
        array_push($game2, $teams[$i]);
    }
```

You can use a flag to fix your existing code as:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($teams); $i++){
    $found = false; // assume its not present.
    for($j = 0; $j < count($game1); $j++){
        if($teams[$i] == $game1[$j]){
            $found = true; // if present, set the flag and break.
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) { // if flag is not set...add.
        array_push($game2, $teams[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, im still be interested to know why my loop isnt working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Your loop doesn't work because every time the element from `$teams` is not equal to the element from `$game1`, it adds the `$teams` element to `$game2`. That means each element is being added to `$game2` multiple times.

Use [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) instead:

```
// Find elements from 'teams' that are not present in 'game1'
$game2 = array_diff($teams, $game1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$teams = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$game1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
$game2 = array_diff($teams,$game1);

// $game2:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
    [6] => 7
)
```